# Pass AngularJS parameter to ActionResult method

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I have google and tried a lot of different solutions to this problem, non of them worked. this is as far as I got. I tried passing it with a `Action Link` and a anchor tag. Tried catching it from the url in the `ActionResult`. This anchor tag produce the right url

**HTML**

```
    <a class="link btn btn-default" ng-href="@Url.Action("CloseProject", "Home")?id={{item.ID}}">@Resource.CloseProjectButton</a>
```

**C#**

```
public ActionResult CloseProject()
    {
        Guid id = new Guid(Request["id"]);

            _fastaSamarbetenRepo.UpdatePropertyBagItemStatusToClosed(id);

        return RedirectToAction("Projekt");
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest using HttpPost action for any code which updates data.

Comment: What specifically is your problem ? If your url is correctly generated what is missing ?

Comment: The url looks correct. But never hits the controller. I havent been able to debugg either. Which is really bad. I am having problems with the SharePoint debugger not attaching to the project.

Comment: when you click the link, what is happening ?

Comment: When I click the link the page refreshes as it should. That means it is passing thru the controller. The weird thing  is that the status code is unchanged. I have a error notification system that filter the errors and shows it to the user in a user friendly manner. But it shows nothing. I really have to get the debugger working.

Comment: put a breakpoint in your action method and debug.

Comment: Yes. I would if it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the `parameter` using `new` keyword.

```
@{
 var url = Url.Action("CloseProject", "Home", new { id = "{{item.ID}}"});
 url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
}
```

and use `data-ng-href`.

```
<a class="link btn btn-default" data-ng-href="@url">@Resource.CloseProjectButton</a>
```

Comment: Thanx. Got the debugger working for split second, it turns out the controller gets the GUID. The problem is elsewhere So Thank you sir!!!